# Can't get FaceTracker class to work on HoloLens 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I'm having trouble getting the [FaceTracker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.faceanalysis.facetracker?view=winrt-19041) to work on HoloLens 2.
As soon as I try to detect the faces with `ProcessNextFrameAsync Method` I get an exception of the following kind:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error`

This is only the first part of the error message, if more information is needed, I can add that.

See this for a minimal example.

```
public async void Start()
{
    var selectedGroup = await FindCameraAsync();
    await StartMediaCaptureAsync(selectedGroup);
}
```

```
private async Task StartMediaCaptureAsync(MediaFrameSourceGroup sourceGroup)
{
    faceTracker = await FaceTracker.CreateAsync();
    this.mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
    await this.mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
    this.frameProcessingTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(ProcessCurrentVideoFrameAsync, timerInterval);
}
```

```
private async Task ProcessCurrentVideoFrameAsync()
{
    const BitmapPixelFormat InputPixelFormat = BitmapPixelFormat.Nv12;
    var deviceController = this.mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController;
    this.videoProperties = deviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;
    VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(InputPixelFormat, (int)this.videoProperties.Width (int)this.videoProperties.Height);

    IList<DetectedFace> detectedFaces;
    try
    {
        detectedFaces = await faceTracker.ProcessNextFrameAsync(videoFrame);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Failed with Exception: {e.ToString()}");
        return;
    }

    videoFrame.Dispose();
}
```

1. i get a suitable camera with `MediaFrameSourceKind.Color` and `MediaStreamType.VideoPreview` with `FindCameraAsync()`. Which works fine in my opinion.
2. start `MediaCapture` and the `FaceTracker` within `StartMediaCaptureAsync()`
3. try to detect faces in `ProcessCurrentVideoFrameAsync()`

Here are the things I have tested and the information I have received:

- I have a picture in the format `Nv12`, `PixelWidth` 1504 and `PixelHeigt` 846
- the permissions in Unity are granted for Webcam, PicturesLibrary and Microphone
- the app is compiled with Il2CPP
- the message `No capture devices are available.` appears after starting the app. In other articles it was mentioned that the permission (Webcam or Microphone) is missing, which is not the case. But may be connected nonetheless.
- I used [Track faces in a sequence of frames](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/detect-and-track-faces-in-an-image#track-faces-in-a-sequence-of-frames) and [Basic Face Tracking sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicFaceTracking) as reference

I am very grateful for every incentive and thought.

#### UPDATE 14. July 2020

I have just tried the `FaceDetector` on several individual images that were stored locally on the HoloLens 2. This works fine.

Even though `FaceDetector` and `FaceTracker` are not identical, they are very similar. So I guess that the problem is somehow related to `MediaCapture`.

Next I will try to capture an image with `MediaCapture` and process it with `FaceDetector`.

If anyone has any more ideas in the meantime, I would be grateful to hear them.

Comment: May I know your HoloLen2 real device's OS version? Also the Unity3D version is good to share. If you deploy the Holographic face tracking sample to your device, may I know what will happen on your side? https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HolographicFaceTracking

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT the OS build of the HoloLens 2 is 10.0.19041.1106. The Version of Unity i use 2018.4.22f1. The idea with the example is good, I already tried that and there the face tracking works. But since it is a compiled version and I am quite new to programming, I could not use it to reverse engineer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an official sample show how to use the FaceTracker class to find human faces within a video stream: [Basic face tracking sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicFaceTracking). And in line 256, that is the main point to get a preview frame from the capture device.

However, base on your code, you have created a [`VideoFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.videoframe?view=winrt-19041) object and specified the properties and format to it, but you are missing invoke [`GetPreviewFrameAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.getpreviewframeasync?view=winrt-19041) to convert the native webcam frame into the `VideoFrame` object.

You can try the following code to fix it:

```
private async Task ProcessCurrentVideoFrameAsync()
{
    const BitmapPixelFormat InputPixelFormat = BitmapPixelFormat.Nv12;
    var deviceController = this.mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController;
    this.videoProperties = deviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;
    VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(InputPixelFormat, (int)this.videoProperties.Width (int)this.videoProperties.Height);

//add this line code.
    await this.mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame);
```

Comment: thanks for the information. Unfortunately I already tried this and get the following error message: 'The request is invalid in the current state.' Any idea what this could be due to? For explanation, I had omitted the creation of the preview, because I had read that it was necessary for data processing, but since it threw the above mentioned error, I only wanted to get the main construct running first.

Comment: @Azzuen Regarding the “The request is invalid in the current state” error, please handle [`MediaCapture.Failed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.failed?view=winrt-19041) and [`MediaCapture.RecordLimitationExceeded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.recordlimitationexceeded?view=winrt-19041) event. They will give you status information for the MediaCapture element. If there is a problem during recording the `Failed` event will let you know that something went wrong and tell you what happened.

Comment: The `RecordLimitationExceeded` event will tell you when you have been recording for too long and the capture was stopped.

Comment: I added the events and experimented further. Eventually I get the error message 'preview sink not set' after adding the method 'await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync'. After that I searched for the error message and found some results where a UI element was linked to the mediaCapture. This is XAML, how can this be solved with HoloLens 2?

Comment: @Azzuen Yes, the GetPreviewFrameAsync method requires a UI captureElement for showing the preview frame, but this is difficult to meet in Unity. Fortunately, the MediaFrameReader will help you get the video frame reference without a UI element, this doc show how to use a MediaFrameReader with MediaCapture to get media frames:[Process media frames with MediaFrameReader
](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-media-frames-with-mediaframereader#handle-the-frame-arrived-event).

Comment: And [Camera frames sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames) is a complete code for this document. We think it will be a good direction for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it and keep you up to date. At the time i get it to work i will accept the answer until then i beg for your patience.